# How to return the compliment of an association using Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js, associations

Is it possible to return the compliment of an associated model using Sequelize?

For example:
Lets say I have two models `Book` & `Author`
and I want to return a list of all `Book`'s including information about its `Author`.
This is pretty simple and is done using the `include` operation.

If I wanted a list of all `Authors` who DID NOT write a specific book, I know I could use the `Author` model and return all `Authors` where `Book.ID != someID` but
how would I return a list of all `Authors` who did not write the book using the Book model?

Edit: both models have a `belongsToMany` association through `someTable`

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query that you're looking to make looks something like

```
SELECT *
FROM book b
LEFT JOIN authors a ON a.authorId <> b.authorid
WHERE b.id = ?
```

I believe you can use the include.on property to achieve this. The Sequelize documentation says that this enables you to 'Supply your own ON condition for the join'. My guess would be something like

```
include: [{
   model: Author
   on: {
      id: {
         [Op.ne]: '$Book(s).authorId'
      }
   }
}]
```

Two things to note:

1. The id and '$Book.authorId' may need to be swapped, I'm not sure.
2. The pluralization of book will depend on what the actual table is named, rather than the model.

There isn't much documentation on how to use this include.on property, so you might have to play around with it.

Comment: Thanks @boc4life. I'll give this a shot and see if this works. I should have mentioned in my original post that both Models have a belongsToMany association through someTable. So, my book model doesn't directly have an authorId field that I can use. I'll play around with it and see if I can get it. Thanks again!